# Strapi: Delete all collection type entries (bulkDelete)

Tags: javascript, json, strapi, headless-cms

How do I delete all entries within a collection type with one request?

I have tried to use the `bulkDelete` endpoint: POST `/content-manager/collection-types/:model/actions/bulkDelete`

But it gives me the following response:

```json
{
  "error": "contentType.notFound"
}
```

I have also tried to pass some json parameters into the body:
`{"ids": ["2", "3"]}`, but its the same result.
In my example I have only one content type `books`, so I use `book` for the `:model` part. What am I doing wrong? I can't find any info in the documentation or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

So for Strapi v3 the answer ist:

Because it is an internal API for the Content Type Manager, it uses the `UID` of the content-type, e.g. `application::book.book`, as also is used in the URL in the Content Type Manager (`/admin/plugins/content-manager/collectionType/application::book.book?page=1&pageSize=10&_sort=id:ASC`)

For v4 it should be different now.